How do I find general solution to any diophantine equation?
I've seen a lot of instances they list out the general solution in form of variables in Diophantine (commonly u,v). How do they find them?
like if there is $$1/x+1/y=1/z$$
can we find a general solution here and how?

There is no algorithm (recipe) that will even tell you whether an arbitrary diophantine equation has solutions (let alone one that describes the general solution). (Not just "nobody has found such an algorithm", but "it has been proven that no such algorithm can exist.")

I think that taking a college course in number theory would put some tools in your arsenal that you could then use to attack some diophantine equations.

Oh I see. Thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted to know. I'll try to detect the patterns when come across the questions and perhaps build my solving capability. I'm currently in high school and I really just number theory.

See also MO: Which types of Diophantine equations are solvable?

See also Grechuk's recently published book, linked in What is the smallest unsolved Diophantine equation?.
